# Where to find the "bulma snippets" for Sublime Text 3?

Tags: text-editors, sublime-text-3, web-development, sublime-text

In the ["Laravel 5.7 From Scratch"](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch-2018) video tutorial one sometimes can see usage of something like macros for [bulma](https://bulma.io/) in  [Sublime Text](https://www.sublimetext.com/) editor.

An example would be the lesson ["Create New Project Tasks"](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch-2018/episodes/18?autoplay=true), from the second `32`. Typing of "bulmatextfield" generates the complete HTML code for a text field (`input`, `label` etc.).

I installed [Sublime Text 3](https://www.sublimetext.com/3) and the ["Bulma CSS Framework Autocomplete"](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Bulma%20CSS%20Framework%20autocomplete) plugin. But I'm still not getting the functionality I saw in the video tutorial.

**How to get "bulma macros/snippets" (working) for Sublime Text 3?**

Answer (score 1):

There is a [package on GitHub](https://github.com/OthmaneBlial/Bulma-Snippets-Sublime-Text-Plugin) by [BLIAL OTHMANE](https://github.com/OthmaneBlial).

You will have to install the snippet using the following flow. You can use it to install any snippet for Sublime Text 2/3.

- Locate the Sublime Text Packages folder: 

   You can find it located at
- Windows: `%APPDATA%\Sublime Text 3\Packages`
- OS X: `~/Library/Application\ Support/Sublime\ Text\ 3/Packages`
- Linux: `~/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/`

Once in the folder open your terminal and

- Run: `git clone https://github.com/OthmaneBlial/Bulma-Snippets-Sublime-Text-Plugin.git`